# What does Can't find file: 'table_name' (errno: 2) mean?

Tags: mysql

I have very little experience with databases, and today I encountered this error today and I have no clue what it means. I have done some research but I haven't been able to find a solution. The error started a day before when some results wouldn't show up. Let's say that the name was table1 then the table form today is table2. So, I was unable to display the information from table1 yesterday, and today I am unable to display content from table1 and table2. Table2 is the one that displays the `Can't find file: 'table_name' (errno: 2)` Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you erase any file from the file system which MySQL is using to store information about either `table1` or  `table2`? Which version of MySQL and OS are you working with?

Comment: `DROP TABLE` is the only proper way to remove a table; sounds like you went into the file system and messed around.

Comment: @RickJames I don't have access to the database, so I don't think I could even do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to your database and run the following:

```
show tables;
```

This will list all tables in the DB. Are the ones you are trying to query from in the list?

Comment: this was done, and they were not in the list. I think we have a rogue "pissed developer". The company did outsource some of the development of the site, then just fired them because they couldn't get anything done.

Comment: That sucks. Sorry to hear that.